# How to get Tables from Navigator Pane and Combine

Tags: powerquery, m

This is the corrected code with the guidance from Alexis.  My PDF returns two tables (and 1 page Table) per output page.  Table001 is a throw away.  I only need even numbered Tables so I use the List.Select to remove the Page Table and List.Alternate to skip odd numbered tables.

```
let
    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents("State_Fico.pdf"), [Implementation="1.3"]),
    TableNames = List.Alternate(List.Select(Table.Column(Source, "Id"),each Text.Contains(_,"Table")),1,1),
    TableList = List.Transform(TableNames, each Source{[Id=_]}[Data]),
    CombineTables = Table.Combine(TableList)
in
    CombineTables
```

This allows me to generate 1 table no matter how many pages the pdf is.

Comment: What do you want to do once you've defined these tables within your query? Append or join them somehow? A single query cannot return multiple tables as the final result.

Comment: Each page of the PDF creates 2 Tables and 1 Page.  If the PDF is 2 pages, 4 Tables and 2 Pages.  Table001 and Table003 are unusable.  Table002 and 004 will get combined (possibly 006, 008).  Because of 003, 002 and 004 are not combining with MultiPage option.  I don't know how many pages the PDF will be so trying to work around that variability to I can code the combination of the Tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't really answer the question in your title, I think the best way to do what you're ultimately after is to not use `Expression.Evaluate` at all and, instead, use list transformation(s).

For example, if you want to append `Table002` and `Table004`, you can use `Table.Combine` on a list of tables, `{Table002, Table004}`.

Here's what the code might look like:

```
let
    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents("State_Fico.pdf"), [Implementation="1.3"]),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(Source),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Page001", type any}, {"Table001", type any}, {"Page002", type any}, {"Table002", type any}, {"Table003", type any}, {"Table004", type any}}),
    ColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),
    TableNames = List.Alternate(List.Select(ColumnNames, each Text.Contains(_ ,"Table")),1,1),
    //--New Steps Below--//
    TableList = List.Transform(TableNames, each Source{[ID=_]}[Data]),
    CombineTables = Table.Combine(TableList)
in
    CombineTables
```

Comment: Really appreciate pointing me in the right direction.